# Additional external wifi and bluetooth adapters through OTG

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, external-keyboard

guys. 
I would like to connect additional wifi and bluetooth to my android tablet to make built in free. For example by external wifi I would like to connect wifi keyboard and native one have free for internet. 
Is that possible? If yes, how to do this?